# find long text passages and split on nth character

Tags: regex, xpath

Is there a way, with xpath, to find words with 30+ characters and add a space after every n-th character?

**example input:**

```
<root>
    <text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametametamet. E Atveroeoseaccusametjustoduodoloresetearebum. Stet clita kasdameta.</text>
</root>
```

**desired outpout**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametametamet. E Atveroeose accusametj ustoduodol oreseteare bum. Stet clita kasdameta.
```

Currently I have this workaorund

```
replace(/root/text, '([^ ]{10})', concat('$1', ' '))
```

Which yields

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametametam et. E Atveroeose accusametj ustoduodol oreseteare bum. Stet clita kasdameta.
```

I thought about combining two replace functions, but this does not yield the desired outcome.

```
replace(/root/text, '([^ ]{30})', replace('$1', '(([^ ]{10}))', concat('$2', ' ')))
```

produces the original string

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametametamet. E Atveroeoseaccusametjustoduodoloresetearebum. Stet clita kasdameta.
```

Comment: I can't find the difference between 'Desired output' and the output from workaround. In what way doesn't the workaround produce the desired result?

Comment: Should have used a more obvious example, it also split shorter words, i.e. with 10+, caused by the „workaround“. Since I couldnt figure out how to split long words into small portions.

Comment: @user10717742 if this answer was this answer helpuf to you consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You approach works, you only got the backreferences wrong. Try it like this.

```
replace(/root/text, '[^ ]{30}', replace('$1', '[^ ]{10}', concat('$0', ' ')))
```

[XPath Online Sample](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Croot%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctext%3ELorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20ametametamet.%20E%20Atveroeoseaccusametjustoduodoloresetearebum.%20Stet%20clita%20kasdameta.%3C%2Ftext%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&=&extract=replace(%2Froot%2Ftext%2C%20'%5B%5E%20%5D%7B30%7D'%2C%20replace('%241'%2C%20'%5B%5E%20%5D%7B10%7D'%2C%20concat('%240'%2C%20'%20')))&=replace(%2Froot%2Ftext%2C%20'%5B%5E%20%5D%7B30%7D'%2C%20replace('%241'%2C%20'%5B%5E%20%5D%7B10%7D'%2C%20concat('%240'%2C%20'%20')))&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)

PS: I've also tried `tokenize(text, "(?<=\G[^\s]{10})")` but XPath/XSLT does not support the required regex features.